Does AWS Documentdb Elastic Cluster need manual version upgrades?
I want to use DocumentDB Elastic Clusters for my application because they support auto-scaling. However, when creating a cluster, I don’t see an option to select the DocumentDB version like I do for instances. Does the cluster need manual version upgrades?
I’m also trying to minimize database downtime as much as possible. Besides version upgrades and data center incidents, is there anything else that could cause the cluster to go down?
Thank you!
